# Interacting with pyscf integral library from Fortran

Tags: pyscf, integrals, fcidump, fortran

I would like to use `libcint`, the integral library in `pyscf` from Fortran. Its webpage has a Fortran API and developer manual, but looks like I still need a tutorial. I posted [here](https://github.com/sunqm/libcint/issues/69), would like to cross post here, since more people are here.

Namely from [here](https://github.com/sunqm/libcint/blob/master/examples/fortran_call_cartesian.F90),
what kind of modifications would be needed to print out results as:

```
from pyscf import gto
mol = gto.Mole()
mol.atom = '''O 0 0 0; H  0 1 0; H 0 0 1'''
mol.basis = 'sto-3g'
mol.build()

kin = mol.intor('int1e_kin')
vnuc = mol.intor('int1e_nuc')
overlap = mol.intor('int1e_ovlp')
eri = mol.intor('int2e')

print('kin', kin.shape, kin)
```

via Fortran?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future !!! Hopefully you get an answer soon!

Comment: Just to clarify a few things. 1. Where is the API for this located, I tried to look on the wiki link from GitHub, but can't connect to the site? 2. What does the Fortran example you linked do? Are you able to get that to run or is that also a part of the question? 3. Do you just want the kinetic energy integrals or all the other ones you make, but don't print in the python example?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. 1. I am not sure. https://github.com/sunqm/libcint mentions 'It provides C/Fortran API to evaluate one-electron / two-electron integrals for Cartesian / real-spheric / spinor Gaussian type functions.'; 2. The Fortran example will check if some integrals are zero, I think (lines 135, 152, 165); 3. I want `kin`, `vnuc`, `overlap`, and `eri`; ultimately, load from Fortran without using python (I am not sure if I use Fortran to load python to load pyscf will take too long time)  The printing line is just for me to have a check.

Comment: @Lancashire3000 dumping the matrices and tensor to disk from Python would be the easiest, if you will any way handle them in-core. The interface is so good, and wrapping a system call to Python isn't that expensive.

Interfacing directly from Fortran to e.g. libcint will require a lot of effort since you need to build the molecule and the basis set and then loop over the shells to compute the integrals shell by shell. PySCF is really fast in my experience, I don't think the overhead is a problem.

Comment: @SusiLehtola, I tried to write integrals to disk, it is too slow for my purpose (I tested the wall time of writting integrals by `psi4`, i think the time for writting disk is similar for `pyscf`. And `pyscf` has a Fortran API, therefore wonder about it). I did not try multiple calls, i.e., Fotran call python, python call pyscf, maybe overhead is ok

Comment: @Lancashire3000 it depends on how your code is bound. If it's integrals bound like an SCF routine, you'll see a lot of overhead. If it's CPU/memory bound - think CCSD(T) - you shouldn't see much of an effect.

Comment: @SusiLehtola, in my project, most times integrals are the bottleneck, and I want it as fast as possible

Comment: Great to see so much discussion here! We also have a [chatroom for PySCF](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112358/python-based-matter-modeling-software) and similar software.

Comment: By the way, the question of how to solve your problem of writing integrals faster, is a different one (should be asked in a separate post), but if you have 100s of GB of integrals, then using Parallel HDF5 on a striped data system might be better, since you can have 100s of nodes printing to the integrals file in parallel. Various efforts were made to implement this since at least as far back as 2016 but I'm not sure where that feature stands at the moment, in the [public NECI repository](https://github.com/ghb24/NECI_STABLE).

Comment: It looks like Qiming Sun added [this file](https://github.com/sunqm/libcint/blob/master/examples/python_call_with_pyscf.py) on GitHub and then closed the issue on GitHub. Did this help you?

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.

Comment: Yes, I tested a bit. The GitHub file helped me to some extend. Though I think I need to get the result right first, then make it faster. So postpone more fortran interactions.

Comment: @Lancashire3000 I am currently trying to implement libcint to a fortran project. This question does not accept answers anymore, so if you still want to know it I can help you. Please contact me, david {dot} sousarj {at} yahoo {dot} com {dot} br.

Comment: @DavidSousa did you get an email from Lacadshire3000? If we re-open the question can you answer it?